# Using `useImperativeHandle` to export ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 following files, called `A.js` and `B.js`.

`A.js`

```
import RefFile from './components/RefFile'

const A = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
   let refRefFile = useRef(null)
   ...

   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      refRefFile
   }))
   
   return (
      ...
      <RefFile ref={refRefFile} />
      ...
   )
}
```

`B.js`

```
import A from './A'

const B = () => {
   let refA = useRef(null)

   const test = () => {
      refA?.refRefFile()
   }

   return (
      <A ref={refA} />
   )
}
```

Can I add the ref of `RefFile` into `useImperativeHandle` to call it from B? I think it will be more comfortable for me to do so. Or is there any alternative way to solve this one? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can work out something like this.

Let, `foo()` is a function in your `RefFile`.

`A.js`

```
import RefFile from './components/RefFile'

const A = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
   let refRefFile = useRef()
   ...

   const accessRefFileFoo = () => refRefFile.foo()

   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      accessRefFileFoo
   }))
   
   return (
      ...
      <RefFile ref={refRefFile} />
      ...
   )
}
```

`B.js`

```
import A from './A'

const B = () => {
   let refA = useRef()

   const test = () => {
      refA.accessRefFileFoo()
   }

   return (
      <A ref={refA} />
   )
}
```

Here, you call the function named `foo()` which is a function in your `RefFile` from your component `B`. Like this, hope you will be able to handle this as you want. If you got any problem, feel free to comment here.